# Insert html title and meta description server side in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using IIS 7 and ASP.NET.

What I would like to do is being able to server side change the **title** and the **meta description** of my index.html file, before it is shown in a webbrowser.

```
<title>Replace with text here on server</title>
<meta name="description" content="Replace with text here on server">
```

I understand I can create either a http handler, http module or http filter in ASP.NET to do this hook up on the request. I found examples of appending html this way, but none showing how to replace/insert text for existing html.

I imagine pseudo code could look like this:

```
Process_Request(file, content)
{
   if (file == index.html)
   {
      content.replace("<title>xxx</title>", "<title>This is what I want title to be</title>"));
      ...same replace for description
   }
   return content to client;
}
```

How can I do this?

**SOLUTION**

I created a content parser module based on the code and example from this [article](https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/modifying-the-static-files-with-a-server-value). Unfortunately the author left out the part about adding the module to web.config, so you should remember to implement that part yourself.

What I did was to put the title and description change into the Write method based on the url segment and a database lookup.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: No, I am not using MVC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Response.Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925433/asp-net-response-filter)

Comment: I know that a flag as duplicate might sound rough but what you need is to use a Response.Filter

Comment: Are you using Web Forms? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Not using Web Forms. Client side I use Angular 4. Server side is ASP.NET. Client and server communicate via web api.

Comment: Then how do you build your pages? Are you just serving .HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

Server side, you can set the Page.Title in the Master page's Page_Load event to change the title.

Also server side, use the HtmlMeta class to change meta properties as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlmeta(v=vs.110).aspx

In Angular you can use the setTitle method of the Title service in Browser platform:  https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

Also Angular Browser platform, Use the Meta service addTag method to manipulate meta tags in Angular: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Comment: This isn't Web Forms, there is no Page_Load or master page.

Comment: He doesn't mention that in the question.

Comment: I know, but it's in the comment.